Override library calls to HttpClients.createDefault()
I'm using a third party library that uses Apache HttpClient 5.5.4. The library internally calls HttpClients.createDefault(). This fails when using any IBM JDK.
External https calls fail with the following error
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The method shutdownOutput() is not supported in SSLSocket
    at com.ibm.jsse2.au.shutdownOutput(au.java:58)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.BHttpConnectionBase.close(BHttpConnectionBase.java:252)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.close(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:71)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.close(DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.java:176)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.PoolEntry.discardConnection(PoolEntry.java:180)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool$PerRoutePool.shutdown(StrictConnPool.java:839)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool.close(StrictConnPool.java:142)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.close(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:277)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.close(InternalHttpClient.java:198)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.close(InternalHttpClient.java:188)

Most answers say to replace HttpClients.createDefault() with HttpClients.custom().useSystemProperties() but this is not possible for code I do not own.
The library does not offer an API to pass in HttpClient objects and the class that is using the HttpClient is final. Is there any other work around besides forking ?

In what way does it fail? An error message with stack trace might be useful.

Part of the choice in using a library is to check whether it is compatible with what you already have in your environment. If the library is not compatible you should not be using it. Now, that aside, you could try to create a class of your own in the same package structure, extend the class you need to fix, and override the method in error to do what you need.

Which library? Which version of the IBM JDK? Instead of asking for a specific solution try describing the problem you are actually having. Otherwise it feels like an XY Problem. Having said that as @JorgeCampos said you are using a library incompatible with your execution environment.

Does it work for any other vendor's JDK? It seems that shutdownOutput() is unsupported for SSLSocket in all JDKs, not just the IBM one.

The library is internal to my organization. There was no indication that it could not work with IBM JDKs. OpenJDK does not cause this issue, but the code base is expecting Xerces to be on the classpath which IBM bundles with their JDK, and Open JDK does not.  Adding Xerces as a 3rd party dependency does not resolve the issue because the package layout is different.

I suspect that if you set the system property jdk.tls.acknowledgeCloseNotify to true, it will start working. But I'm not all that familiar with SSL sockets, so I'm not sure.

It appears this is an issue with JRE's that do not support "TLS half-close policy". Open JDK 8/1.8 fully works. However, the IBM JDK8 used at my organization does not. I resolved this issue by using httpClient-5.3.1.
